# EXCEL:delete b1 if a1 font color is red

Tags: excel

If a1 is written in red color , delete content of cell b1
If a2 is written in red color , delete content of cell b2
If a3 is written in red color , delete content of cell b3
If a4 is written in red color , delete content of cell b4
If a5 is written in red color , delete content of cell b5 and so on
...please help

Comment: Please show your own effort. Do you know how to write code in VBA? I also suggest to take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Looks rather like a homework to me... Please read the rules of this site first.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Sub BetterRedThan()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.Font.Color = vbRed Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).Clear
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```